# Migrating from CharField to PostgreSQL ArrayField-of-CharField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I have a Django model with a `CharField`.  I'd like to migrate it to a PostgreSQL [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) containing `CharField` elements. It looks like [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) should be involved here, but how specifically should I do this?

Original model:

```
from django.db import models

class TestModel(models.Model):
    test_field = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        choices=[("a", "AAA"), ("b", "BBB")],
        blank=True,
        default="",
    )
```

The database table has some rows created from this model:

```
from my_app.models import TestModel
t1 = TestModel.objects.create()  # test_field == ''
t2 = TestModel.objects.create(test_field="a")
```

Now I'd like to migrate to:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class TestModel(models.Model):
    test_field = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=[("a", "AAA"), ("b", "BBB")]),
        default=list,
        blank=True
    )
```

...with any case where `test_field` is, in the original model, the empty string `""`, becoming the empty list in the new model & DB field, `[]`.

In Python-space this would look like:

```
convert_ftype = lambda val: [val] if val else []
```

So that the two model instances from above become:

```
t1 = TestModel.objects.create()  # test_field == []
t2 = TestModel.objects.create(test_field=["a"])
```

Running simply `./manage makemigrations && ./manage migrate` throws a `django.db.utils.DataError`, which is not surprising.

Comment: You should have both fields in a first migration, then in a data migration (RunPython) populate the ArrayField based on the value of the CharField, then remove the CharField (3rd migration) then rename the ArrayField (4th migration).

Comment: Well, you've thoroughly convinced me to look for other options @dirkgroten